# C++ Covariant Parameters - Design Pattern

Tags: c++, polymorphism, covariance, contravariance

Take the following simplified C++ class hierarchy as an example. What I want to accomplish is that `Service` provides a virtual method for saving arbitrary `Model` objects. But each subclass of `Service`, e.g. `BoxService` should and can only save `Box` objects.

Due to the fact that C++ does not support covariance in method parameters I cannot simply declare the save method in `BoxService.h` like:

```
void save(Box box);
```

My question is, is there any preferred design pattern or best practice for that problem? Or should I check in the implementation of the save function in `BoxService.cpp` if the arriving Model object is of type Box and throw an exception otherwise?

**Model.h**

```
class Model {
private:
    int id;
};
```

**Box.h**

```
class Box : public Model {
private:
    int size;
};
```

**Service.h**

```
class Service {
public:
    virtual void save(Model model);
};
```

**BoxService.h**

```
class BoxService : public Service {
public:
    void save(Model box);
};
```

**BoxService.cpp**

```
void BoxService::save(Model box) {
    // TODO: save box and make sure that box is of type 'Box' and not any other subtype of 'Model'
}
```

Comment: This breaks the polymorphism. If I am given a `Service` and I call `save(model)`, it shouldn't fail if I happen to be given a `BoxService`. Contravariant parameters go the other way. If `Service` can save a `Box`, then `BoxService` could take `Model` as a parameter, since callers through `Service` will pass `Box`es, which are `Model`s, but callers directly through `BoxService` could pass any `Model` type. This is what C++ doesn't support.

Comment: Why should `BoxService` inherit `Service`?  A bag of apples is not a bag of fruit.

Comment: I agree! Is it even possible to lay out a design similar to the one described above without breaking polymorphism?

Comment: Well, I am going to have multiple subclasses of `Service` and all of them will have common methods like `save`, `delete`, etc. I want to place the `Service` class as a kind of Interface for all sub services.

Comment: What you're describing sounds sort of like a [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern), but it feels slightly different to me for some reason.

Comment: `template <class Model> class Service`.

Comment: This actually seems very close to the Expression Problem. There, you have node types (int literal, addition, if) and operations (eval, pretty-print, type). Here, you have model types and operations provided by services.

Comment: This is not inheritance, this is composition backwards. Make a `template<typename ModelType> ServiceImpl;` and make a `Service` that inherits / contains all of these `ServiceImpl`s. Add it a way to iterate all of them and if you need polymorphic save (which you can most of the time avoid) provide a visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you sound like you want to group operation implementations by model type. I'll explain a more OOP approach.

Separate `Service` from the implementations, but we're going to get rid of the pesky parameter:

```
class Service { ... };
class ServiceImpl {
    virtual ~ServiceImpl() {}
    void save() const = 0;
    void remove() const = 0;
};
```

Each implementation will be lightweight and support the operations, but will take the parameter in the constructor:

```
class BoxService : public ServiceImpl {
    Box _b;

public:
    BoxService(Box b) : _b(b) {}

    void save() const { ... }
    void remove() const { ... }
};
```

Now we have an abstract factory to create implementations as we need them:

```
class ServiceImplFactory {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<ServiceImpl> create(Model m) const {
        if (auto b = dynamic_cast<Box*>(m)) {
            return std::make_unique<BoxService>(*b);
        } else if (auto x = dynamic_cast<X*>(m)) {
            return std::make_unique<XService>(*x);
        } else {
            assert(!"Not all Models covered by Service implementations");
        }
    }
};
```

Now `Service`:

```
class Service {
    ServiceImplFactory _implFactory;

public:
    void save(Model m) const {
        return _implFactory.create(m)->save();
    }

    void remove(Model m) const {
        return _implFactory.create(m)->remove();
    }
};
```

Further steps:

- Engineer a solution that gives a compile-time error instead of asserting.
- Allow both more model types and more operations to be added without changing (much) existing code. This should be equivalent to the Expression Problem. Notice that this approach of grouping operations by model type requires a much more widespread change to add a new operation than it does to add a new model type. The reverse would be true for using a visitor and grouping model types by operation. There are solutions to the Expression Problem, such as [object algebras](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2012/ecoop2012.pdf), but they can be a bit more obscure.

Answer (score 2):

Here's perhaps a more functional approach:

Pair each model type with its implementation:

```
template<typename T, typename ExtraType>
struct WithType {
    T value;
    using extra_type = ExtraType;

    WithType(T value) : value(value) {}
};
```

Define a `Model` as a variant instead of an inheritance hierarchy:

```
using Model = std::variant<WithType<Box, BoxService>, WithType<X, XService>>;
```

Now visit the variant:

```
class Service {
public:
    void save(Model m) const {
        visit([](auto withService) { 
            typename decltype(withService)::extra_type service;
            service.save(withService.value);
        }, m);
    }

    void remove(Model m) const {
        visit([](auto withService) { 
            typename decltype(withService)::extra_type service;
            service.remove(withService.value);
        }, m);
    }
};
```

Comment: Almost, but you don't have type safety guarantee for BoxService, which in your model might containg BagService.

Comment: @lorro, I don't understand. By defining `Model` in this way, you attach the correct service type to the model object. If you call `save(Box{})`, it will use `BoxService`. If you call `save(Bag{})`, it will use `BagService`, assuming the definition of `Model` is correct. If you mess this up and attach `BagService` to `Box`, I believe any `visit` invocation will be a compiler error.